# UTF8 string not rendering properly in HTML iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

In my project am passing regional language (malayalam)  text (length : 1900) from xcode WebViewDidFinishLoad to javascript function which written in html page

```
 function loadArticle(heading, img, desc, date){
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;

            if(img == null || img == "null"){ 
                document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
            }else{
                addImg(img);
                document.getElementById("image").style.display = "block";

            }

            addHeading(heading);
            addDesc(desc);
            addDate(date);
        }


    function addDesc(desc){
            alert(desc); //is working fine . i can see my big text here
            document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = desc;
            return desc;
    }
```

am also using these meta tags

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
```

in xcode

```
if (img!=NULL){

            loadingString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadArticle('%@','%@','%@','%@')",newNewsTitle,detail_ImageURL,trimmedDescString,detail_date];
            [detail_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loadingString];

        }else{
            loadingString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadArticle('%@','%@','%@','%@')",newNewsTitle,@"null",trimmedDescString,detail_date];
            [detail_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:loadingString];
        }

    }

    [detail_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadArticle('%@')",loadingString]];
```

in my html part

```
<body>
        <div id="heading" style="font-size:26px;"></div>
        <h6 id="date"></h6>
        <p>
            <img id="image" src="" width="auto" width="auto" style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:0px;"/>
            <span id="description" width="320" style="font-size:18px;"> </span>
        </p>
    </body>
```

when i hard code in xcode and pass big text then its working fine (any language)  but when i parsing from xml and passing value to html from xcode its not showing (javascript alert showing correct values) .

Please help